# Hover hand pointer not working in AmCharts Stock chart

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I have two graphs displayed using AmChart. On hover pointer displays for one, but doesn't work for another. On hover working for first dataset graph when hovered hover the round pointer but it doesnt work for the second data set graph.
I'm using the `showHandOnHover` property but still not working.
[DEMO](https://codepen.io/jay-raj/pen/NyQOdZ)
Here is the code:

```
var chartData1 = [];
var chartData2 = [];

generateChartData();

function generateChartData() {
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 500);
    firstDate.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

        var a1 = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 + i)) + 100 + i;
        var a2 = -1 * Math.round(Math.random() * (100 + i)) + 200 + i;

        chartData1.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: a1
        });
        chartData2.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: a2
        });
    }
}

AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    type: "stock",

    dataSets: [{
            title: "first data set",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value"
            }],
            dataProvider: chartData1,
            categoryField: "date"
        },

        {
            title: "second data set",
            fieldMappings: [{
                fromField: "value",
                toField: "value2"
            }],
            dataProvider: chartData2,
            categoryField: "date",
            compared: true
        }
    ],

    panels: [{

            showCategoryAxis: false,
            title: "Data set #1",
            recalculateToPercents: "never",
            stockGraphs: [{
                id: "g1",
                valueField: "value",
        bullet: 'round',
        showHandOnHover: true,
                comparable: true
            }],

            stockLegend: {

            }
        }, {

            showCategoryAxis: true,
            title: "Data set #2",
            recalculateToPercents: "never",
            stockGraphs: [{
                id: "g2",
                valueField: "value2",
        compareGraphBullet: 'round',
        compareGraphShowHandOnHover: true,
                compareField: "value2",
                comparable: true,
                visibleInLegend: false
            }],

            stockLegend: {

            }
        }
    ],

    chartScrollbarSettings: {
        graph: "g1"
    },

    chartCursorSettings: {
        valueBalloonsEnabled: true,
        fullWidth:true,
        cursorAlpha:0.1
    },

    periodSelector: {
        periods: [{
            period: "MM",
            selected: true,
            count: 1,
            label: "1 month"
        }, {
            period: "YYYY",
            count: 1,
            label: "1 year"
        }, {
            period: "YTD",
            label: "YTD"
        }, {
            period: "MAX",
            label: "MAX"
        }]
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try to add just `circle {cursor: pointer}` to your stylesheet?

Comment: didn't think that way. Thanks :)

Comment: @iJade most of the time, simplest solutions are so obvious that we forget about them ;). if it did the job, do not forget to mark this answer as a solution.